# dbpedia /flash how to?

Tags: java, flash, actionscript, visualization, dbpedia

I am interested in visualising data from dbpedia in flash but I am a little out of my depth technically... 
I know a bit of actionscript, javascript and some php but I'm not familiar with SPARQL or java.
The documentation I can find on it is a little over my head.
I have a couple of questions before I totally ruling it out:

• Has anyone come across an example/tutorial for accessing dbpedia data through flash?

• Im a little hazy on how you work with dbpedia. Do you download the entire database or can you connect to a database on their server?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I found this page which was helpful:
http://blog.3kbo.com/2008/08/11/dbpedia-examples-using-linked-data-and-sparql/

It looks like you can query their database online rather than having to download it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a lot of data [here](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads351) without needing to know SPARQL.  It's in rdf triple format, but that should be relatively easy to parse and add to your own database.  Or if you want to do focused queries, you can use the link that you found.

As far as visualization there are quite a few good libraries available in Flash/Javascript.  In flash I recommend [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/).  In Javascript the following are worth looking into:

1. [Javascript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)
2. [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
3. [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the DBpedia RelFinder [1]. It is an open source project [2] written in adobe flex that visualizes the relation between two DBpedia resources.

It connects to the DBpedia SPARQL Endpoint to retrieve information.

[1] http://relfinder.dbpedia.org/

[2] http://code.google.com/p/relfinder/